# Validate fields conditionally based on another field in Yup and Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have a problem in validation. I wanted that if `access` value is 1 then you can select the `start_date` and `end_date` BUT if the value of `access` is not 1, then you can only select today.

Codesandbox

[image: Edit 63973773/error-when-setting-an-input-in-reactjs-label-is-over-overwrites-the-value-of (forked)]

```
export const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  access: yup.number().nullable(),
  start_date: yup.string().required('Select start date'),
  end_date: yup.string().required('Select end date'),
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of string validation you can use date validation, just make sure to set correct messaging!:

```
import moment from "moment";
...
const today = new Date().toDateString();
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  access: yup.number().nullable(),
  start_date: yup.date()
    .typeError("Invalid date")
    .required("Select start date")
    .when("access", {
      is: 1,
      otherwise: (d) => d.min(today, "Should be today's date")
          .max(today, "Should be today's date")
    }),
  end_date: yup.date()
    .typeError("Invalid date")
    .required("Select end date")
    .when("access", {
      is: 1,
      otherwise: (d) => d.min(today, "Should be today's date")
          .max(today, "Should be today's date")
    })
});
```

Update stackblitz can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-material-ui-date-picker-with-yup-validate-forked-96cqg).

Comment: When access is 1 then you can select any date. But when the value of `access` IS NOT 1, you can only select today.  and by the way, pls use date-fns. I have posted my codesandbox in my question. Thank you